# Facebook iOS SDK Hang at App Start

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

I have not started any of facebook view or method in appDidFinishLoadingWithOptions: but stil when I start app at first, then stop and restart it, it hangs. If i press the pause button i can see the stack trace shown in image.

[image: Stack Trace Image]

This code in method **applicationDidBecomeActive** was creating the issue. Anyone know what can be a possible reason. Removing this solved my issue.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) {
[FBSession.activeSession close]; // so we close our session and start over
}

if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
}

}
```

Comment: have u show ur app delegate Facebook codings

Comment: I have not setup or send any call to any FB method in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to navigate the page to another view controller so try this.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIViewController *splashController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *detailednewscontroller=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splashController];
[self.window setRootViewController:detailednewscontroller];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: r u serious? this is an issue with me.